# Sharing server port with modules which update client via socket.io

Tags: node.js

I am implementing a node server which in addition to serving pages also consists of a set of sub-modules which are used to report data via socket.io. Each module is pretty independent from the core server - each module has a timer which processes some data and emits the results back to the web client(s). But due to the structuring of the code/modules, I'm running to a problem related to how the port connection to the server used/shared and was wondering if there was a recommended pattern on how to do this?

The server has a very basic setup and then requires the modules:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
app.listen(8888);
function handler (req,res) { ... }

// Here's where the sub-processing happens
var module1 = require('./module1.js');
var module2 = require('./module2.js');
...    
var moduleN = require('./moduleN.js');
```

Then each module has the following structure:

```
// Socket stuff
var io = require('socket.io').listen(port);// Not sure how to share server port???
io.sockets.on('connection', onConnect);
function onConnect(socket) { ... }

function sendUpdateToClients(type,data) {
    io.sockets.emit(type,data);
}

// Timed stuff
setInterval(someProcessing,someInterval);
function someProcessing() {
    ... // process some data here
    sendUpdateToClients(type,data);// Emit the data to clients
}
```

I've currently have this code running separate from my MEAN application, while I try to best figure out how to organize the code.

I guess my questions are:
- What are best practices to organize sub-modules updating modules? 
- Should I be passing a socket reference from the server to each module? If so, how would this best be done?
- Or should I be returning something from the modules back to the server, so it does the updating? If so, how would this best be done?
- Should each module use their own port, separate from the server port?
- Or does this whole organization of code suck and is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can export your module as a function.

```
//module1.js
module.exports = function(port){
var io = require('socket.io').listen(port);// Not sure how to share server port???
io.sockets.on('connection', onConnect);
function onConnect(socket) { ... }

function sendUpdateToClients(type,data) {
    io.sockets.emit(type,data);
}

// Timed stuff
setInterval(someProcessing,someInterval);
function someProcessing() {
    ... // process some data here
    sendUpdateToClients(type,data);// Emit the data to clients
}
}
```

Then inside your server file.

```
module2.js
var module1 = require('./module1.js')(8888);
```

Comment: Your proposed solution gave me a EADDRINUSE error, but I used the module.exports concept that you suggested - good idea. I now define the sockets connection in the server, then pass 'io' to the sub-module(s), and allow the submodules to use this to emit. It's not elegant due to encapsulation concerns ... but it works.